# Integration of Custom made Password Reset page with validation for Flutter app using Firebase backend

Tags: flutter, dart, google-apps-script, firebase-authentication, reset-password

I have a flutter app, which has user auth (from Firebase) and the password has certain requirements. But the usual password reset page that firebase offers only checks if there is 6 characters. So I made a custom page with all validation required for the password. It is a html file, a css file and a js file. Those work perfectly. But I am very unsure of where I should put this code to make this my custom reset password landing page from firebase. I know after the code is done, I just need to link my url to the reset password inside firebase. But on adding the code provided on the official documentation and following the comments on where to add the functions which provide validation, my page stops working. The validation does not seem to works as intended.

How do you advice me to add the code on the official website @ ([https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler[text]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler%5Btext%5D))??

I will attach here my code without the code in the official documentation. That is, the page that has the password validation working, but does not do anything else with the input.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Password Validation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aleo|Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Password Validation</h2>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password"
        onInput="check()" />
       <br>
         <div id="set" >
        <div id="count">Length : 0</div>
        <i id="see" onclick="see()" class="far fa-eye"></i>
         </div>
           <div id="check0">
                <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>  <span> Length more than 7.</span>
           </div>
           <div id="check1">
                <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>  <span> Contains Uppercase </span>
           </div>
           <div id="check2">
                <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>  <span> Contains 3 Lowercase.</span>
           </div>
           <div id="check3">
                <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>   <span>Contains numerical character.</span>
           </div>
           <div id="check4">
                <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>  <span>Contains special character.</span>
           </div>
           <div style="text-align:center;">
            <button type="button">Reset Password</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var is_visible = false;

function see()
{
    var input = document.getElementById("password");
    var see = document.getElementById("see");
    
    if(is_visible)
    {
        input.type = 'password';
        is_visible = false; 
        see.style.color='gray';
    }
    else
    {
        input.type = 'text';
        is_visible = true; 
        see.style.color='#262626';
    }
    
}

function check()
{
    var input = document.getElementById("password").value;
    
    input=input.trim();
    document.getElementById("password").value=input;
    document.getElementById("count").innerText="Length : " + input.length;
    if(input.length>7)
    {
        document.getElementById("check0").style.color="green";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("check0").style.color="red"; 
    }
    
    if(/[A-Z]/.test(input))
    {
        document.getElementById("check1").style.color="green";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("check1").style.color="red"; 
    }
    
    if((input.length - input.replace(/[a-z]/g, '').length >=3))
    {
        document.getElementById("check2").style.color="green";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("check2").style.color="red"; 
    }
    
    if(input.match(/[0-9]/i))
    {
        document.getElementById("check3").style.color="green";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("check3").style.color="red"; 
    }
    const specialChars = /[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
    if(specialChars.test(input)==false)
    {
        document.getElementById("check4").style.color="red";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("check4").style.color="green"; 
    }
    
}
```

**style.css**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background:linear-gradient(to right, #6441a5, #2a0845);
    display: flex;
    font-family: monospace;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.container {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
h2 {
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #6441a5;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#set
{
    display:block ;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
}
#count
{
   display:inline-block;
   position:relative ;
   margin:4%; margin-bottom:2%;
   color:#000; font-size:18px;
   text-indent:40px;
   font-weight:bolder;
   
}
#see
{
    display:inline-block;
    color:gray;
    margin:auto; 
    /*float: right;*/
    text-align: right;
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-top:10px;
    cursor:pointer; 
    transition-duration:0.2s;
}
input[id='password']
{
    padding: 10px;
    border:none; 
    width:80%;
    outline:none;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2a0845;
    display:block; 
    position:relative;
    font-size:27px;
    text-align:center;
    top:50px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left:35px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    user-select:auto;
    font-family:Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    transition-duration:600ms;
}
i
{
    font-size:23px;
    transition-duration:600ms;    
}
#check0,#check1,#check2,#check3,#check4
{
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   margin:4%;
   color:red; font-size:18px;
   width:92% ;
   
}
span
{
    margin:10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input:hover
{
    border-bottom:5px solid #6441a5;
}
button {
    border: none;
    color: pink;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: purple;
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
  }
```